# Dynamically recalculate mouse position for a selection box when changing page size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

#### I have a script to draw a selection box over a grid (just a .png image) however I have an error where the selection box is drawn in the wrong place.

I think it's because the script which the mousedown position uses calculates top and left on page load. If the page is resized before creating a selection box, it uses the original calculations of top and left and is therefore not in the correct position.

Is there a way to fix this problem without completely bastardising my script?

Below is the code used along with a .zip and a jsFiddle, thank you for your help!

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Naxgq/)

### [.zip](http://www.speedyshare.com/TJdVR/download/grid.zip)

CSS:

```
  body{
    background-color: #3AB3F0;
  }

  #board-background{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
    margin: 25px auto 25px;
    position: relative;
    background: url(https://abs.twimg.com/a/1366134123/t1/img/wash-white-30.png);
    border: 0px solid #e5e5e5;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
  }

  #board {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #FFF;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
  }

  #board img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    user-drag: none;
    -moz-user-select: none; 
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
  }

  #selectionBox {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 3;
      display: none;
      background-color: red;
      min-width: 0px;
      min-height: 0px;
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      opacity: 0.8;
  }
```

HTML:

```
    <html>

        <head>

            <link href="css/test.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/board_script.js"></script>

        </head>

        <body>

        </body>

    </html>
```

JS:

```
// GRID CREATION SCRIPT //
// -------------------- //


function creategrid(){

//Outside background for the board   
    var BoardBackground = document.createElement('div');
    BoardBackground.id = 'board-background';
    BoardBackground.class = 'board-background';
    document.body.appendChild(BoardBackground);

    //Generated image
    var Board = document.createElement("div");
    Board.id = 'board';
    Board.className = 'board';
    BoardBackground.appendChild(Board);

    //grid image
    var grid = document.createElement("img");
    grid.id = 'grid';
    grid.className = 'grid';
    grid.src = "media/grid.png";
    Board.appendChild(grid);

}


// Selection Box Script //
// -------------------- //


var isDragging = false,
    dragStart,
    cellSpacing = 10,
    gridOffset,
    selectionBox;

function getMousePos (e) {
    return {
        'left': Math.floor((e.pageX - gridOffset.left) / cellSpacing) * cellSpacing .toFixed( 0 ),
        'top': Math.floor((e.pageY - gridOffset.top) / cellSpacing) * cellSpacing .toFixed( 0 )
    };
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    creategrid(10);
    gridOffset = $('#board').offset();
    selectionBox = $('<div>').attr({id: 'selectionBox'})
      .appendTo($('#board'));

    $('#board').on('mousedown', function(e){
        isDragging = true;

        var pos = getMousePos(e);
        dragStart = pos;

        selectionBox.css({
            left: pos.left,
            top: pos.top,
            width: 10,
            height: 10
        }).show();

    });

    $('#board').on('mousemove', function(e){
        if(!isDragging)
            return false;

        var pos = getMousePos(e);
        var diff = {
            'left': pos.left - dragStart.left,
            'top': pos.top - dragStart.top
        };

        selectionBox.css({
            left: Math.min(pos.left, dragStart.left),
            top: Math.min(pos.top, dragStart.top),
            width: Math.abs(diff.left),
            height: Math.abs(diff.top)
        });

    });

        $('#board').on('mouseup', function(e){
        isDragging = false;
    });

});
```

Media:
(I need 10 rep to post a third link, so here's plaintext and 'code')

oi43.tinypic.com/33opjtd.jpg

```
[grid.png](http://oi43.tinypic.com/33opjtd.jpg "grid lined image with transparent background")
```

Other things that I need help with:

---

- another minor error is the fact that, when selecting to the left and the top, the box rotates around the top left corner rather than the bottom right (try selecting the entire grid from the bottom right square).

  - I think that this has something to do with putting an if statement around the math.abs in the css and subtracting 10px from either side... but I can't work it out
- Also in the future I want to be able for the user to upload an image and have it displayed over the selection box (dynamically changing in size) it should be possible by changing the css of the selection box... I might open a separate question for that though.

Comment: a. Do users often resize in the middle of the selection process? If so the mouse has likely performed the resizing and is no longer in the position it was prior to resizing. 2. You could bind the positioning to the resize event. http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: I've noticed during testing that people tend to load the page prior to making the window fullscreen, which was when I first stumbled across this bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single line can solve your selection probleme on resize :

```
$(window).resize(function(){gridOffset = $('#board').offset();})
```